# Triggering transition on componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a transition using react and css. I want to add a class to the `span` to create the animation - See example below.

Does anyone know if the issue is with the css or my javascript.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    class: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      class: "active"
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="progress-bar-container">
        <span
          className={this.state.class ? 
                     "progress-bar" : 
                     `${this.state.class} progress-bar`}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.progress-bar-container {
  border: 0;
  height: 4px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.progress-bar {
  -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari */
  transition: width 5s;
  width: 0%;
}

.progress-bar.active {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: What is the issue ? Have you checked in the debugger if the required class is getting applied or not ?

Comment: What is your expected and actual output? Your code looks fine

Comment: my expected out put is to have the progress bar to move from 0% - 100% as the answer below has demonstrated

Answer (score 3):

You could use a different approach and append `active` class with `setTimeout` method.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    class: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.refs.progressBar.classList.add("active"), 100)
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className = "progress-bar-container" >
        <span className="progress-bar" ref="progressBar"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , rootElement);
```

```css
.progress-bar-container {
  border: 0;
  height: 4px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  transition: width 5s;
  width: 0px;
}

.progress-bar.active {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: nice, I see this works, is it because the component mounts with the active `className` overwriting the `.progress-bar`, meaning the transition never occurs?

Comment: why `setTimeout()`?

Comment: @peter flanagan That is what I also think, and its not working without setTimeout.

Comment: yea, seems to be the explanation - you're not 100% sure either tho?

Comment: I think the transition works when some transition happen after the dom is loaded (for example if we add new class), but in this case component re renders itself with that new class so there is no transition.

Comment: yeah, interesting one - prob one for the powers that be at React HQ to clarify! :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `requestAnimationFrame()` to trigger the transition on mount. I'd presume that doing this is more robust than relying on a `setTimeout()`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.setState({
            class: "active"
        });
    });
}
```

Source: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/handling-componentdidmount-issue-css-transition